# How to calculate column mean at intervals of row values in R?

Tags: r, mean, sliding-window

I have [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH2Cm.png) which has 253 rows(locations on a chromosome in Mbps) and 1 column (Allele score at each location). I need to produce a dataframe which contains the mean of the allele score at every 0.5 Mbps on the chromosome. Please help with R code that can do this. thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Generally a minimum reproducible example would be preferred. Question: Do you have an 'interval' column? If not, can you generate one? Then you can just restructure with ddply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture in this case is adequate to construct an answer but not adequate to support testing. You should learn to post data in a form that doesn't require re-entry by hand. (That's why you are accumulating negative votes.)

The basic R strategy would be to use `cut` to create a grouping variable and then use a loop construct to accumulate and apply the mean function. Presumably this is in a dataframe which I will assume is named something specific like `my_alleles`:

```
 tapply( my_alleles$Allele_score,    # act on this vector
                                     # in groups defined by this factor
         cut(my_alleles$Location, 
             breaks=seq(0, max(my_alleles$Location), by=0.5)
             ), 
                                     # with this function
         FUN=mean)
```